# Retrieve MobilePush notifications on client on demand without using MobilePush SDKs

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, marketingcloudapi

Is it possible to retrieve MobilePush notifications that were sent to a device on-demand ("pull" notifications)? Is there a REST API to retrieve the notifications that were sent to a specific user/device?
I am trying to setup a web app that mirrors the notifications that were sent to a user's Android device. Our Android app is currently using the SMFC SDK to register for push notifications.

I found this [REST API for retrieving notifications](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/connect_resources_notifications_list.htm), would that be the appropriate API?

Comment: I do not think this is possible.

Comment: FWIW the doc you listed is not an SFMC dev doc

Comment: Hi @BillMote so there is no way for a user who logs in to a new device to have old push messages? I guess Marketing Cloud cannot do this but outside MC?

Comment: Push messages are device specific. When you request a push token from Apple/Google, that token is for that device specific installation. Installing your application on a new device would result in a new installation with a new/different token specific to that device. This isn't a Salesforce/Marketing Cloud thing. This is an Apple/Google/How Push Notifications Work thing.